# OrientDB: how to search over specified field in manual lucene index?

Tags: lucene, orientdb

I'm using OrientDB 2.1.8 Community and built-in Lucene index. How I can define which field I want to use during the search in **manual** index? I.e. work with manual indexes in a manner like described on [Working with Multiple Fields](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Full-Text-Index.html#working-with-multiple-fields) page in the documentation?

Below is short example to show what I'm trying to do.

```
CREATE VERTEX CONTENT {"name": "squirrel"}
  // rid = #9:2
CREATE VERTEX CONTENT {"name": "scrat", "description": "Scrat was an acorn-obsessed saber-toothed squirrel"}
  // rid = #9:3

CREATE INDEX manual FULLTEXT ENGINE LUCENE STRING,STRING
INSERT INTO INDEX:manual (key,rid) VALUES ('squirrel', #9:2)
INSERT INTO INDEX:manual (key,rid) VALUES (['scrat', 'scrat was an acorn-obsessed saber-toothed squirrel'], #9:3)
```

Now query `SELECT rid FROM INDEX:manual WHERE key LUCENE 'squirrel'` will return both `#9:2` and `#9:3`.

How I should change the type of the key and/or `INSERT INTO INDEX` commands to be able to define which field I want to use? For example, query like `SELECT rid FROM INDEX:manual WHERE key LUCENE 'name:squirrel'` should return only `#9:2`, but not `#9:3`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to use manual indexes?

Comment: The keys should be positional. And you should be able to use in query with a convention like k0,k1.

Comment: @wolf4ood: I'm trying to implement full-text search over all string properties of all vertices (although it may look strange). I don't know which properties the vertices may have, so I can't define properties in schema and create automatic index on them.
As a possible workaround, I created manual index and use dynamic hooks on class V to update it. In my case I can search over all fields at the same time, but can't define only one field to search if needed.

Comment: @wolf4ood: Maybe it's too strange use case or there is better solution for this, but use of built-in tools is more convenient in comparison with external solutions like Solr or ElasticSearch, and if it possible it would be great.

Comment: @xscaratt i understand your use case. It is not strange. You want a search engine across all your vertices. https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/82

Should work in a positional way.
K0,K1...
SELECT rid FROM INDEX:manual WHERE key LUCENE '(k0:squirrel)'

Comment: @wolf4ood thank you for your help, but it doesn't work :( Query with `'(k0:squirrel)'` returns both vertices, and query with `'(k1:squirrel)'` returns nothing... Am I correct in using `STRING` as a key type in `CREATE INDEX` (although I tried to use other types with the same result)? Or should I use Java API to populate the index (as mentioned [here](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/82)) instead of SQL?

Comment: I've inspect the code. There is a bug in that part
I will open an issue about that. Should be fixed soon for the next release

Comment: Opened here.
https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/5708

Comment: @wolf4ood thank you!

Comment: Fixed
https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/5708

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with `create index manual FULLTEXT ENGINE LUCENE STRING,STRING METADATA {"analyzer":"org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.KeywordAnalyzer"}` and it works

```
CREATE VERTEX CONTENT {"name": "squirrel"}

CREATE VERTEX CONTENT {"name": "scrat", "description": "Scrat was an acorn-obsessed saber-toothed squirrel"}

create index manual FULLTEXT ENGINE LUCENE STRING,STRING METADATA {"analyzer":"org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.KeywordAnalyzer"} 

INSERT INTO INDEX:manual (key,rid) VALUES ('squirrel', #9:0)

INSERT INTO INDEX:manual (key,rid) VALUES (['scrat', 'scrat was an acorn-obsessed saber-toothed squirrel'], #9:1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but it's not exactly what I mean... I need the use cases: full text search across all vertices, and search across all vertices by specified field only. It's more like search engine mentioned [here](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/82).